# My SELECT SUM query in PHP is not including the last insert's value

Tags: php, mysql, sum, average

I have a database such as:
Name, Product, Score, Feedback

Each row (with Dave being the first insert and Sam as the last) for example is:
Dave, Apple, 3, Good
Jim, Pear, 5, Awesome
Sam, Peach, 2, Okay

When I run my code, it would only add Dave's and Jim's to total 8. It's not adding Sam's score value until another new insert has executed.

```
<?php  
    //connect to the database
    $connectionstring = mysql_connect('localhost', 'teammystic', 'teammystic1' ) or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());  
    //select the database  
    mysql_select_db('my_teammystic') or die('Could not select database: ' . mysql_error());  
    $Query = "SELECT SUM(SCORE) AS VAL FROM customerFeedback";  
    //execute query  
    $queryexe = mysql_query($Query) or die('Could not query database: ' . mysql_error());  
    $dataArray = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryexe);  
    // Free resultset
    mysql_free_result($queryexe) or die('Could not free result: ' . mysql_error());
    //disconnect from database
    mysql_close($connectionstring) or die('Could not close database: ' . mysql_error());
?>
```

I am trying to a make an average score display, any help is very appreciated thank you.

Comment: Your Query works fine. Check this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/57de8/1/0)

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, it works on sqlfiddle but I am using Altervista for my web hosting and its not adding the last insert. I checked this by writing a print statement. Do you have any clues as to why this happens?

Comment: can you share your hosted domain?

Comment: http://teammystic.altervista.org

Comment: i mean the page where you added this code. can you print the result in it? and share that link.

Comment: http://teammystic.altervista.org/Feedback.html

use that link and type in any random info and it should lead you to the php where the code is, if i link you directly to the php page it will break because the feedback page has a form post.

I've already set it up as well to print the results at the top

Comment: Are you executing this query before inserting new row? I know that this is dumb but there is no other way select query could miss that last row

Comment: That was the problem, wow I can't believe I didn't catch that. Thank you man.

Comment: You are Welcome. I'm happy that i could help